# Get an average number for multiple embedded documents MongoDB

Tags: php, json, mongodb, highcharts

I am working with highcharts to make a drilldown chart. This will display multiple projects, with an average value and will drilldown in columns with every value. The problem is, I can't get the average number per projects.. 
My JSON from the mongo looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f4dd6c45db428df9a5541b"),
    "id" : 68,
    "project_code" : 13110202,
    "samples" : [
                {
                        "sample_name" : "1678_2",
                        "perc" : "75.97"
                },
                {
                        "sample_name" : "2012_1B-5",
                        "perc" : "75.33",
                },
                {
                        "sample_name" : "2012_1B-8",
                        "perc" : "77.28",                 
                }]
},    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f4dd6c45db428df9a5541a"),
    "id" : 70,
    "project_code" : 1235125,
    "samples" : [
                {
                        "sample_name" : "Ben",
                        "perc" : "30.97"
                },
                {
                        "sample_name" : "Anna",
                        "perc" : "81.25",
                },
                {
                        "sample_name" : "Sarah",
                        "perc" : "80.23",                 
                }]
},
```

I am trying to look through the document, through the embedded document samples, get all the perc_mapped values, calculate the average and put this in a JSON used for the HighChart. The code which I have now:

```
foreach ($id_array as $char) {
            $cursor = $collection->find(array("_id" => new MongoId($char)));
            foreach ($cursor as $document) {
                if (is_array($document['samples'])) {
                    foreach ($document['samples'] as $samples) {
                        array_push($perc_total, $samples['perc']);
                        $average_of_foo = array_sum($perc_total) / count($perc_total);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var_dump($average_of_foo);   


        foreach ($id_array as $char) {
            $cursor = $collection->find(array("_id" => new MongoId($char)));
            foreach ($cursor as $document) {
                if (is_array($document['samples'])) {
                    foreach ($document['samples'] as $samples) {
                        $array =
                            array("name" => $document['project_code'],
                              // Here is will add the average
                                "y" => (float) $samples['perc'],
                                "drilldown" => $char
                            );
                        array_push($array_data, $array);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include the desired JSON output? Besides, you may need to change your schema design i.e. convert the `perc_mapped` values to numerical ones instead of the strings currently.

Comment: So, what part of your current code is not working?

Comment: I have got it to work! I will update my question shortly with the solution.